# php bool statement to check if file has been uploaded is not working properly

Tags: php, file-upload, forms

I have a simple php page where you add a contact and you have the option of giving them a picture. If no picture is uploaded then the contact will be given a default picture already on the server.

The problem is that the bool test I use to check if the user uploaded a file or not ALWAYS comes back as true, even when the user hasn't uploaded a file

this is the code from my html form

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Contacts Photo</td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>
```

and this is the php I use to see if a file has been uploaded or not

```
$haspicture = false;

if (empty($_FILES['fileField'])){
    $haspicture = false;
}

if (!empty($_FILES['fileField'])){
    $haspicture = true; 
}
```

if someone could please tell what I've been doing wrong, it'd be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in the `$_FILES` array are always arrays themselves. That's because the form element is always submitted with the form, even if it contains no content. In other words, they're never "empty". Try `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what you're getting.

You should check like this:

```
if (isset($_FILES['fileField']['error']) && $_FILES['fileField']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php.

Comment: YES! thank you so much!!! I wasn't really aware it was never empty, thanks for the help, I greatly appreciate it!